# Google Spanner Efficient LIKE on Index

Tags: performance, google-cloud-spanner

Hye everyone,

Haven't really found a decent answer to this.

Say, I have a table that contains FIRST_NAME, and I have created an INDEX for this. Now, for performance reasons, I could easily do a STARTS_WITH query on the index, which would be substantially faster than a full table scan. However, if I wanted to find everyone who has "at" in their name (LIKE "%at%"), this would trigger a full scan. Is there any way to somehow keep the efficiency of an indexed search, but still do a full text search? Or... ElasticSearch to the rescue?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, a full scan cannot be avoided. However, if the secondary index created on FIRST_NAME does not have many columns, then the scan would be on a more narrow structure.